# Elasticsearch - Get all tokens for index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How do I get all tokens/words that have been indexed for an index.
NOT for a single field.
I know how to do this:

```
GET /MyIndexNameHere/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": 
    { 
      "CommonWords": { "terms": { "field": "MyFieldName"}}      
    }
}
```

I have indexed 5 text fields.
I would like the common words used.

I tried:

```
"CommonWords": { "terms": { "field": "_all"}}
```

But I get the mesage that "Fielddata is not supported on field [_all] of type [_all]"

Do I need to change something something in my Index?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: But why? Can you please exlain why you are doing?

Comment: My client wants to see the most used words. I will then allow the user to select from this list to narrow the results.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use ES 5,
In ES 5 if you have string field you need to map this field as type text or keyword,
For aggregation you need keyword.
You're query is aggregation, so MyFieldName have to be keyword type, change it to keyword and it's will work